# Fetch posts with attachments in a certain category?

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, join

I need to retreive a list of posts that have (at least) one attachment that belongs to a category in WordPress.

The relation between attachments and categories I made by myself using the WordPress default method.

Here's the query that i'm running right now:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM `bma_posts` AS post
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `bma_posts` AS attachment
        JOIN `bma_term_relationships` AS relationship ON
            relationship.`object_id` = attachment.`ID`
            AND
            relationship.`term_taxonomy_id` IN (17,15,16,5)
        WHERE
            attachment.`post_parent` = post.`ID`
            AND
            attachment.`post_type` = 'attachment'
    )
    AND
    post.`post_type` = 'post'
    AND
    post.`post_status` = 'publish'
ORDER BY post.`post_date` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The problem now is that I can't get the attachment.`ID` to know "who" included that post on the query.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I kind of disagree with your editting/expanding on this question. For your information [I submitted it for review on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281462/1446005).

Comment: @RandomSeed - I agree. That question as its phrased now is entirely different.

Comment: "The attachment.ID". Is this bma_posts.ID? If so, that will exist in the Select clause as written. It also isn't clear where "who" is derived. What column in what table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ...
From wp_posts As P
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From wp_posts As P1
                    Join wp_term_relationship As WTR1
                        On WTR1.object_id = P1.ID
                            And WTR1.term_taxonomy_id In(3)
                Where P1.post_parent = P.Id
                    And P1.post_type = 'attachment'
                )
    And P.post_type = 'post'
Order By p.post_date DESC
Limit 15
```

Comment: @TiuTalk - Ah. You did not mention what you needed in the result beyond the wp_posts table. Can you provide a sample of the output you are seeking.